# How to make PowerShell Module Logging more granular

Tags: powershell, logging, module

Is it possible to turn on only select cmdlets in PowerShell Module Logging?  For example under the Microsoft.PowerShell.Core Module, would it be possible to only turn on logging for Get-History cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the -Verbose switch parameter to enable Verbose-Logging